# reiterative add and subtract values to find group with max cumulative value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This is a hard one to explain for me, but here we go:

I'm trying to add variable values to the group with the highest cumulative value, and assign that group to the variable in my dataset (Microsoft SQL Server).

Some variables can belong to 2 (or more!) different groups, and what I need is to determine what group has the highest value. If I add *that* variable's value to the group, the group's sum will increase, which can affect all the other variables that also could belong to that group.

Say I have 3 groups, that have these initial values:

```
GROUP   INITIAL VALUE
A       7
B       10
C       5
```

And I have these variable with their own value:

```
VARIABLES   VALUES
AB          20
AC          35
BC          5
```

AB can belong to group A or B, AC can belong to A or C, etc. (whichever one has the highest value). This is essentially an issue of grouping my data.

If I just assign the variables to whatever group has the highest current value, the new group cumulative values will look like this:

```
GROUP   SUM
A       42 (A+AC)
B       35 (B+AB+BC)
C       5  (C)
```

But now, group A has a higher group sum than B, so variable AB should be moved to group A instead:

```
GROUP   SUM
A       62 (A+AB+AC)
B       15 (B+BC)
C       5  (C)
```

Now, in my dataset I have many different groups and variables, so adding 1 variable's value to the group sum can affect a lot of other variables, which will affect a lot of groups and so on.

What I need is some function or some guidance on how to tackle this problem. Any help is appreciated!
Thank you :)

Comment: sorry forgot to include that. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

The result of all those *"movements"* of VARIABLES between GROUPs would be that the top GROUP would have all the VALUES of all the VARIABLES that belong to that group plus own INITIAL VALUE. With that in mind we can just go on and calculate the maximum *potential* total for each group and take the top one:

```
With [INITIAL] ([GROUP], [VALUE]) As (
    Select 'A',  7 Union
    Select 'B', 10 Union
    Select 'C',  5
),   [VARIABLES] ([VARIABLE], [VALUE]) As (
    Select 'AB', 20 Union
    Select 'AC', 35 Union
    Select 'BC',  5
)
Select Top 1
    [GROUP],
    [VALUE] + (Select SUM([VALUE])
               From [VARIABLES]
               Where CHARINDEX([GROUP], [VARIABLE]) > 0 --< VARIABLE belongs to the GROUP
    ) As [CUMULATIVE VALUE]
From [INITIAL]
Order By [CUMULATIVE VALUE] Desc
```